# Django post_migrate signal been called multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-signals

I have created a post_migrate with the goal to sync all the data inside the table whenever a migration runs. This is the snippet of the post_migrate file:

```
# signals.py
@receiver(post_migrate)
def full_sync_if_model_change(plan, **kwargs):
    if plan:
        models_set = set()
        for file, _ in plan:
            for model in file.operations:
                try:
                    model = SyncModel.objects.get(
                        app_name=file.app_label, model_name=model.model_name
                    )
                    models_set.add(model)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    pass
        print(models_set)
        if models_set:
            for model in models_set:
                model.set_full_sync()
                run_update_sync(model, False)
        return
```

However, when I run a migration, it is called 6 times; as you can see in the output of migration:

```
evandro@evandro-340XAA-350XAA-550XAA:~/Desktop/.../test_service$ python3 manage.py migrateOperations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, django_cron, lakehouse_sync, sessions, test_models
Running migrations:
  Applying test_models.0019_auto_20211026_2052... OK
set()
set()
set()
set()
set()
set()
```

I'll add here also the apps file:

```
class LakeSyncConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "lake_sync"

    def ready(self):
        """Import signals"""
        import lakehouse_sync.core.delete_action

        from . import signals
```

I have no idea what to do, I tried to add this return statement, but it doesn't work, because the function is called all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post_migrate` signal is sent once for every app migrated, even if there were no changes. Pass the `sender` parameter when connecting your signal to only run your function once when your app has migrated

```
def full_sync_if_model_change(plan, **kwargs):
    ...


class LakeSyncConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "lake_sync"

    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(full_sync_if_model_change, sender=self)
```